# How do I implement a macro that creates a quoted string for _Pragma?

Tags: c, macros, pragma, stringify

I want to have a macro that's invoked like this:

```
GCC_WARNING(-Wuninitialized)
```

which expands to code like this:

```
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wuninitialized\"")
```

I'm not having luck getting this to work, as the usual tricks of preprocessor joins and stringifying don't seem to apply or I don't know how to apply them here.

Answer (score 15):

With the little help of preprocessor magic:

```
#define HELPER0(x) #x
#define HELPER1(x) HELPER0(GCC diagnostic ignored x)
#define HELPER2(y) HELPER1(#y)
#define GCC_WARNING(x) _Pragma(HELPER2(x))

GCC_WARNING(-Wuninitialized)
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work, probably due to the fact that it doesn't put \" around -Wuninitialized. The macro usage above yields the following GCC error: ignoring #pragma GCC diagnostics [-Wunknown-pragmas]

Comment: It does place quotes around -Wuninitialized. The problem was a typo `diagnostics` instead of `diagnostic` -- I've fixed it in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Would it also be acceptable if the macro argument is enclosed in single quotes? If so, you could use this:

```
#define GCC_WARNING(x) _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored '" #x "'")
```

When calling it like `GCC_WARNING(-Wuninitialized)` it expands to

```
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored '" "-Wuninitialized" "'")
```

I had to make use of the string concatenating behaviour of C (`printf("a" "b");` is the same as `printf("ab");`) here since using `"'#x'"` in a macro would avoid that `x` is expanded.

Comment: Almost... actually "_Pragma" has a special meaning for gcc. I was posting a similar solution, but I realized that it doesn't work with my gcc because the preprocessor complains ("error: _Pragma takes a parenthesized string literal").

Comment: That won't work -- `_Pragma` interprets its argument before strings are concatenated, so it will see two strings, not one. Unlike `printf`, it is a special construct which follows special rules.

Comment: Ah, how silly, it didn't occur to me that this was a GCC-specific question. I thought `_Pragma` was some custom debug function but now that I look at the name of the macro, I should've known better.

Comment: In fact `_Pragma` is not GCC-specific. It's part of the C99 standard to allow macros to expand to a pragma. However, the user asked about a GCC-specific use case, but the question would still be valid for generic pragmas as well.

Comment: @Lindydancer: Interesting! I didn't even realize that it's part of the C99 standard. Learned something new today. :-)