# How define macro as _Pragma with macro argument

Tags: arguments, literals, pragma

I have been writing C++ for a while but have very little macro experience. I have read some of the other questions on this topic but I just can't quite translate them to my problem.

I want to define a macro such that coding `ENUM_PRAGMA(foo)` produces `_Pragma("enum(foo)")` which I intend to have the effect of `#pragma enum(foo)`

(The compiler supports `_Pragma("string")`.)

I have tried multiple variations of

```
#define ENUM_PRAGMA(siz)  \
_Pragma( "enum(" #siz ")" )
```

but can't get any of them to work.

Based on [How do I implement a macro that creates a quoted string for _Pragma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724644/how-do-i-implement-a-macro-that-creates-a-quoted-string-for-pragma) I tried

```
#define HELPER1(x) enum( x )  
#define HELPER2(y) HELPER1(#y) 
#define ENUM_PRAGMA(siz) _Pragma(HELPER2(siz))
```

but I'm still not quite there. (Error is `string literal was expected but enum was found` so I guess my HELPER2 is not quoting the string.

Can anyone please humor me on this? Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I got it.

I defined a general purpose macro STRINGIFY:

```
#define STRINGIFY(str) #str
```

Now the real macro comes down simply to

```
#define ENUM_PRAGMA(siz) _Pragma(STRINGIFY(enum(siz)))
```

Thanks for your patience.